# How to use querySelector in a PopUp Modal

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic, queryselector

```js
const pokemonContainer = document.getElementById('pokemonContainer');

pokemonContainer.innerHTML += `
<div>
    <section class="all-comments"></section>
</div>
`;

const allComments = document.querySelector('.all-comments');
allComments.appendChild(<h1>Hello World</h1>);
```

```html
<div class="row" id="pokemonContainer"></div>
```

I'm trying querySelector('.all-comments') but as it's in pokemonContainer that's why It's returning undefined. Someone can please guide me on how to query select something placed in innerHTML as given above?

Comment: I think that you should use _append_ instead of _innerHTML_.

Comment: You just need to call `appendChild` with a proper parameter.

Comment: @IlijaIličić I can't change that because It's a pair programming activity and it wrote by someone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) expects a node element as parameter, you can create a text node using [`Document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode):

```
allComments.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello World'));
```

**Demo:**

```js
const pokemonContainer = document.getElementById('pokemonContainer');

pokemonContainer.innerHTML += `
<div>
    <section class="all-comments"></section>
</div>
`;

const allComments = document.querySelector('.all-comments');
allComments.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello World'));
```

```html
<div class="row" id="pokemonContainer"></div>
```

**Update:** You cannot pass `<h1>Hello World</h1>` directly to `appendChild()`. First you need to create a node of the type you want, then set the text, finally pass that node to the method.

**OR:** You can try using [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
const pokemonContainer = document.getElementById('pokemonContainer');

pokemonContainer.innerHTML += `
<div>
    <section class="all-comments"></section>
</div>
`;

const allComments = document.querySelector('.all-comments');
allComments.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<h1>Hello World</h1>');
```

```html
<div class="row" id="pokemonContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please check out the question again because I edited the question now. replace 'hello world' with <h1>Hello World</h1>. It's expected to be HTML element not a text node.

Comment: @ZainSadaqat, added another solution for the update you have made in the question, please check:)

Comment: The problem isn't with the h1Node, it's with allComments. I can't access allComments because it's being generated dynamically.

Comment: @ZainSadaqat, though the issue is not quite clear to me, you can try using `insertAdjacentHTML()`  `allComments.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<h1>Hello World</h1>')`.....please check the updated answer:)

Comment: appendChild is my secondary requirement. The primary requirement is I want to query select from the innerHTML part. Which I'm unable to do so.